# How to use one query instead of multiple

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have multiple dates and i need to count how many records against a specific date in Database. I am using the below code which is working but.. the problem is it will excuse a new query every time inside the loop. I am sure there is a better way to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
  for ($i = 0; $i <= $total_difference; $i++){
     $date = strtotime("+$i day", strtotime($start_date));
     $check_date = date("Y-m-d", $date);

     // Here i have to check the record against $check_date
    $query = $this->db->select("SELECT COUNT(task_date) as COUNT FROM 
    time_management");
    $this->db->from('time_management');
    $this->db->where('task_date',$check_date);
    $result = $this->db->get()->row_array();
    $count = $result['COUNT'];
    echo "count for $check_date is $count";

 }
```

Comment: use case function of mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: So you want the count of `task_date` in `time_management` for each of the total dates as defined by your `for` loop?

Answer (score 5):

You're executing this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(task_date) as COUNT 
FROM time_management 
WHERE task_date = ?
```

where the question mark is a date.

What you need to do is `GROUP BY task_date` and set the begin date and end date like this:

```
SELECT task_date as TASKDATE,
       COUNT(task_date) as COUNT 
FROM time_management 
WHERE task_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY task_date
```

The two question marks are the first and last date you want the count of.

As vivek_23 remarked it is handy to have the task_date in your results, so I added that.

I'll leave you to translate this to the specific methods that Codeigniter uses, that should be easy (I don't use it).

If you need zero count results, which will not be present in the result of this query, you can add them with PHP. This is easier than trying to force MySQL to give you zero counts for dates that aren't in the database. Like this:

```
// suppose you start with these
$start_date       = '2018-05-04';
$total_difference = 6; 

// and suppose the result of your query looks like this
$counts = ['2018-05-04' => 5,
           '2018-05-06' => 3];

// then you can insert zero count results like this:
for ($days = 0; $days <= $total_difference; $days++) {
  $date = addDaysToDate($start_date,$days);
  if (!isset($counts[$date])) $counts[$date] = 0;
}

function addDaysToDate($date,$days)
{
  $timestamp = strtotime("+$days day",strtotime($date));
  return date("Y-m-d",$timestamp);
}
```

Note that I defined a function to add days, that seems useful.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(task_date) as COUNT,task_date` instead of `SELECT COUNT(task_date) as COUNT`. He may probably want to use the task_date further in the code.

Comment: suppose i follow your logic and execute the following query
SELECT COUNT(task_date) as COUNT FROM time_management WHERE task_date BETWEEN '2018-07-05' AND '2018-07-09' GROUP BY task_date
Its showing only 2 counts because inside these date only two task added but it was suppose to show all the counts (0) between these two dates even when they are not been added

Comment: @vivek_23: Yes, of course, I forgot that, and will add it.

Comment: @Nadeem Sorry, we overlooked that. Will let you know

Comment: @Nadeem If you need count 0 for other dates not present in task_date table, you may have to add a separate new table with all dates and add it as join in this query. Refer : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month

Comment: Yes, zero count are not included. Let me think about that. It's not easy to do in mysql, I would add zero results in PHP. Think about it, you use mysql to retrieve data and then PHP to shape it to what you need. That's quite normal. I'll add the code to do this to my answer.

Comment: That's simple and nice.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have an array of dates: ('2018-05-04', '2018-05-05', '2018-06-01'), implode them into a string and use IN operator, group the results by date:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(task_date) as cnt,
    `task_date`
FROM 
    time_management
WHERE
    `task_date` IN ('2018-05-04', '2018-05-05', '2018-06-01')
GROUP BY `task_date`;
```

The best solution for non-existing records I can think of is to select all the existing records in the loop, and delete them from your array of dates. Those left will be non-existing and their COUNT will be zero.

Comment: I also want to count those dates in which task has not been added. means count 0

Comment: @Nadeem You mean, the dates, where the record doesn't exist?

Comment: @Nadeem Let me see.

Comment: @Nadeem Updated the answer.

Comment: That's look logical, let me try it then i will verify the answer.